# android intent passing null value

Tags: android, android-intent

i am totally stuck up in solving my problem. i have tried all possible ways to get it done but in vain. Please , an anyone have a look at following code and help me out...
i am new to android/ java environment.

i have activity A from where i trigger Activity B for result. Activity B is a Form which the user has to fill and has to Submit it by pressing "SAVE button " on the form. the data in the form gets stored in database (which is working fine ) and the the Activity B returns to activity A with a string (provided by the user)

when it returns to Activity A with a sting a listview should be updated with the value of that string.

here is my code :

to start intent from A:

```
 Intent ccard_intent= new Intent(this, create_ccard.class);
 startActivityForResult(ccard_intent,start_activity_for_ccard);
break;
```

above code works fine. activity B starts (which has a form to be filled by user)

in activity B , after the user fills out the form he presses save button.
the entries are stored in Db and it prompts the user for a name to be given for that particular entry. i have used alertdialog for the purpose. now note that the entry in the databse has the name(string) provided by the user in alertdialog, now i want the same string to be passed to activity A:

my code after clicking SAVE BUTTON:

```
case R.id.Ccard_save_btn:

     //do operations 

 CcardString =myobj.toString();

AlertDialog.Builder save_btn_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
save_btn_builder.setTitle("Enter the Card Name");
final EditText input= new EditText(this);
  save_btn_builder.setView(input);

  save_btn_builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Card_name=input.getText().toString();
        myDatabse mydb = new myDatabse(getBaseContext());
        mydb.open();
          mydb.insertCard(Card_name, type, CcardString);

          mydb.close();


    //i have intent declared at the begining along with along with Card_name

        i.putExtra("card_name", Card_name);

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);


        finish();
    }
});

  save_btn_builder.show();
```

now , the intent successfully returns to activity A but with a null value in "card_name"!!
i cant figure it out why???

now my onActivityResult code is:

```
  protected void onActvityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Log.d("activity ccards", "in on activity resume");
    if(requestCode == 788 && resultCode== RESULT_OK){
 new_ccard = data.getStringExtra("card_name");
     ccards_arraylist.add(new_ccard);

    adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //adapter3 is the adapter for the listview
    }

}
```

Comment: check first it stored in intent first

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: i have checked it using toasts in Activity, it returns null!

Answer (score 0):

You have never set a value for the variable input. So how will :

```
Card_name=input.getText().toString();
```

return a value ?

You could try something like this :

```
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int count, int after)
    {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int before, int count)
    {
        Card_name=input.getText().toString();
    }
});
```

You will have to have the textWatcher to get the changed text value. Otherwise it would be null.

Comment: the text in the "input" is has to be entered by the user himself.

Comment: what i think is , i have no problem in getting the string in Card_name, i have checked it using Toast, moreover, i have used the same name to store the card in my database which is also working fine. The error is in passing the string through the intent, and not getting the string value.

Comment: After you do a putExtra, it looks like you havent started the intent.